# Using Windows Server 2012 Foundation as a Commercial Web Server

Tags: windows-server-2012

If I'm happy with the 1 CPU and 32GB memory limit, is there anything else that would stop me using Windows Server 2012 Foundation as a commercial public facing web server for my start-up?

I'm hoping that it doesn't have any limits on incoming IIS sessions/connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can, it's a possible role and the incoming connections on IIS aren't limited like on dekstop windows versions. Consider however that Windows Server 2012 Foundation is only sold with bare metal hardware, that it's not usable on virtual servers, and that upgrading might cost more than buying a standard edition from the start.

All the limits of the 2012 foundation edition are listed [in this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679892.aspx)

Comment: `that it's not usable on virtual servers`, sorry for digging out such old thread, I think it is not fully accurate, because it's technically possible (to virtualize Windows Fundation 2008/2012), therefore you can use it on hardware which was received with Windows Fundation (licence is not violated - `Foundation must be installed on a physical server` and it'll be). Source: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN163931/EN